# Python - Parse string in "0xDE 0xAD 0xBE 0xEF" form to a bytearray

Tags: python, arrays, string, parsing, hex

There is plenty of sample code to accomplish this in a few lines of code.  Is there a library in python 3.2 that can do this in one call?  If not, what's the minimum code to do this?

I'd be happy to get the results in any list-like (indexable and iterable) result...

Edit: You guys are fast!  I like this one:

```
byte_collection = bytes(int(x, 16) for x in some_string.split())
```

Comment: Why is there an issue with "a few lines of code?"  Is it really important whether the solution's one line or many, given that you will probably lock this code up in a function somewhere?

Comment: The accepted solution doesn't require defining my own method to hide how to do it.  It's a pet peeve of mine to unnecessarily wrap standard python libraries in application code.  It's just unnecessary.  I like the solution below that I accepted and see no reason to wrap it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
3>> bytes(int(x, 16) for x in '0xDE 0xAD 0xBE 0xEF'.split())
b'\xde\xad\xbe\xef'
```

Comment: @Corey: No one said it was supposed to.

Comment: Just a heads up for those who may find this.

Comment: The 2.x version: `''.join(chr(int(x, 16)) for x in '0xDE 0xAD 0xBE 0xEF'.split())`

Answer (score 3):

List of integers:

```
list_of_ints = [int(x, 16) for x in inputstr.split()]
```

String of bytes (ASCII characters):

```
string_of_bytes = ''.join(chr(int(x, 16)) for x in inputstr.split())
```

In Python 3:

```
string_of_bytes = bytes(int(x, 16) for x in inputstr.split())
```

Comment: `int()` understands the `0x` so there is no need to strip it off

Answer (score 2):

If you want it as a list of integers, this should work, assuming `s` contains your string:

```
[int(piece, 16) for piece in s.split()]
```

If you want it as a string, you can use this:

```
''.join(chr(int(piece, 16)) for piece in s.split())
```